# How to reach the nested child elements of same name and formats

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest, how to reach the inner mrow/mo contains braces.

In given samples, first level braces are converted prpoerly to 'MFENCED' when mrow (if its first and last child should be 'MO' with braces signs). But unable modify the second-level brackets, where those are also having 'MFRAC' as descendant. Template match should from 'MROW' (as given).

**XML input:**

```
<article>
<body>
<math id="m1">
    <mrow>
      <mo>(</mo><!--first level braces open-->
        <mi>u</mi>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <mi>g</mi>
        <mi>=</mi>
        <mrow>
            <mo>(</mo><!--second level braces open-->
            <mfrac>
                <mrow><mn>1</mn></mrow>
                <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
            </mfrac>
            <mo>)</mo><!--second level braces close-->
        </mrow>
      <mo>)</mo><!--first level braces close-->
    </mrow>
</math>

<math id="m2">
    <mrow>
        <mo>(</mo>
            <mrow>
                <mfrac>
                    <mn>8</mn>
                    <mn>9</mn>
                </mfrac>
            </mrow>
        <mo>)</mo>
    </mrow>
</math>
</body>
</article>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mrow[matches(child::*[1][name()='mo'], '^(\(|\[|\{)$')]
                            [matches(child::*[position()=last()][name()='mo'], '^(\)|\]|\})$')]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="descendant::mfrac">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:element name="mfenced">
                    <xsl:attribute name="open"><xsl:value-of select="child::*[1][name()='mo']"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="close"><xsl:value-of select="child::*[position()=last()][name()='mo']"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:for-each select="*">
                            <xsl:if test="position()=1"/>
                            <xsl:if test="not(position()=1) and not(position()=last())">
                                <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=last()"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Result:**

```
<article>
<body>
<math id="m1">
    <mrow>
        <mfenced open="(" close=")"><mi>u</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>g</mi><mi>=</mi>
            <mrow>
            <mfenced open="(" close=")"><!-- this node or modification required, because, within this MFRAC presents, then it should convert to 'MFENCED' -->
                <mfrac>
                    <mrow><mn>1</mn></mrow>
                    <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
                </mfrac>
            </mfenced>
            </mrow>
        </mfenced>
    </mrow>
</math>

<math id="m2">
    <mrow>
        <mfenced open="(" close=")">
            <mrow>
                <mfrac>
                    <mn>8</mn>
                    <mn>9</mn>
                </mfrac>
            </mrow>
        </mfenced>
    </mrow>
</math>
</body>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mrow[mo = '(']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="mo[. = '(']">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="self::mo[. =  '(']">
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-ending-with="mo[. = ')']">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="current-group()[last()][self::mo[. = ')']]">
                                    <mfenced open="(" close=")">
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(position() eq last())]"/>
                                    </mfenced>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article>
   <body>
      <math id="m1">
         <mrow>
            <mfenced open="(" close=")">
               <mi>u</mi>
               <mo>+</mo>
               <mi>g</mi>
               <mi>=</mi>
               <mrow>
                  <mfenced open="(" close=")">
                     <mfrac>
                        <mrow>
                           <mn>1</mn>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                           <mn>2</mn>
                        </mrow>
                     </mfrac>
                  </mfenced>
               </mrow>
            </mfenced>
         </mrow>
      </math>
      <math id="m2">
         <mrow>
            <mfenced open="(" close=")">
               <mrow>
                  <mfrac>
                     <mn>8</mn>
                     <mn>9</mn>
                  </mfrac>
               </mrow>
            </mfenced>
         </mrow>
      </math>
   </body>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, plus one for nice grouping method.

Comment: And one doubt sir, Why second MROW is also a child, why it is not reached in -for-each select="*". Please suggest.

Comment: Is your question related to my XSLT code? Or to the one in your question? If you have an input sample for which my suggestion does not work then consider to edit your question and to show it.

Comment: No Sir, in my xslt code, for-each select="*" and <xsl:apply-templates/> also used. Then that second MROW can also modify? (my XSLT code). U r suggestion working for many formats, even heterogeneous braces too.